# Bases de datos: Optimizar tabla para búsqueda de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb, optimización

Partiendo de las siguientes tablas (a modo de ejemplo):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int auto_increment primary key
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id int auto_increment primary key
);

CREATE TABLE rel (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  id_table1 int not null,
  id_table2 int not null,
  str varchar(20) not null,
  foreign key (id_table1) references table1 (id),
  foreign key (id_table2) references table2 (id)
);
```

El problema es que la consulta "común" (la más usada e importante) selecciona **la última** inserción donde los valores *id_table1* e *id_table2* de la tabla *rel* son *id_table1 = i* y *id_table2 = j* y la consulta en si **me resulta demasiado costosa. ¿Alguna solución?**

```
SELECT * FROM rel WHERE id_table1 = i AND id_table2 = j ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**¿Por qué me resulta demasiado costosa?**
Bueno, una propiedad que tiene esta base de datos es que tanto *table1* como *table2* tienen muy pocos registros, al contrario de *rel* que tiene muchos más. Una opción que consideré fue la de crear una tabla para cada registro de *table1* y guardar los otro valores, pero esto se me hace poco llevadero ya que cualquiera de las dos tablas pueden crecer (poco pero pueden) y hacer de esto un lío.
Algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_element (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  id_table1 int,
  id_table2 int,
  str varchar(20) not null,
  foreign key (id_table1) references table1 (id),
  foreign key (id_table2) references table2 (id)
);
```

Gracias de antemano!
Saludos.

Comment: debes usar [JOIN](https://diego.com.es/principales-tipos-de-joins-en-sql) si quieres comparar otras tablas

Comment: No se termina de entender, cual es el problema o duda?

Comment: Por la consulta que estás haciendo y según comentas es la más habitual, te sugiero que definas un índice en `rel` compuesto: `id_table1 + id_table2`

Comment: Y ya que estamos.. Bienvenido Mauricio Aguerrido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta SQL que presentas:

```
SELECT * FROM rel WHERE id_table1 = i AND id_table2 = j ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Debería ser instantánea con el siguiente índice:

```
create index ix1 on rel (id_table1, id_table2, id);
```